# Change defaultPageTransition in jquery mobile 1.4.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to know how to change jquery mobile default Page Transition to slide ?

i tried

```
$("div[data-role=page]").bind("pagebeforeshow", function ( e , data ) {
    console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ page before show");
    $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.transition='slide';

});
```

and

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  //apply overrides here
  $("div[data-role=page]").pagecontainer( "change" , { transition: "slide" } );
});
```

But both did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.extend( $.mobile , {
    defaultPageTransition: 'slide'
  });
});
```

Comment: Nope it still having fade transition

Answer (score 2):

**Solution :**
Okay found the answer this mobileinit need to call before jq mobile load

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
                    alert("yes");
                    console.log("mobile initialize .....");
                  $.extend( $.mobile , {
                    defaultPageTransition: 'slide'
                  });
                });


            </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
});
```